# difference between 'anything' and "anything" in sqlite database

Tags: database, sqlite

what is the difference between 'anything' and "anything" in sqlite database?
As far i have understood, single quotes are used to denote strings while double quotes are for keywords.
But, i have used `column_name="value"` as where clause in a query and database accepts that query. why?
thanks..

Comment: I'm not sure if this question needs the android tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from the sqlite webpage;

http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html

> If a keyword in single quotes (ex: 'key' or 'glob') is used in a
>   context where an identifier is allowed but where a string literal is
>   not allowed, then the token is understood to be an identifier instead
>   of a string literal.
>
> If a keyword in double quotes (ex: "key" or "glob") is used in a
>   context where it cannot be resolved to an identifier but where a
>   string literal is allowed, then the token is understood to be a string
>   literal instead of an identifier.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, beware of using double "quotes" if you mean a 'literal string'!
I was puzzled today by:

```
sqlite> select * FROM words WHERE word = "id";
<nothing>
```

versus:

```
sqlite> select * FROM words WHERE word = 'id';
13556|id
```

Schema:

```
sqlite> .schema
CREATE TABLE words (
 id integer primary key,
 word   varchar(64)
);
```

As there is a column named `id`, "id" is interpreted here as the column named `id`, not as the literal string 'id'! Best avoid double quotes if you don't need them.